# HTML E-mail - Using a background image

Tags: html, css, email

I have created my HTML e-mail using tables, and the table has a background image which comes through fine in most web based e-mail clients.

I am struggling to get the background image to show in Outlook.

My latest attempt, I have tried doing the following:

```
<img style='position: absolute; z-index: 1; height:1157px; width:712px;top:0;left:0;border:0;z-index:1;' src="http://www.site.com/background.jpg" />

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding:0;line-height: 100% !important;font-family: Verdana,Times New Roman,Times,serif; font-size: 12px; position: relative; z-index: 2;" width="712" height="1153">
...
</table>
```

This image comes through in outlook, although the table is below the image.

I am guessing this is because Microsoft Word doesn't support "position" or "z-index".

I am looking for a push in the right direction to create this HTML e-mail, I don't mind redoing it from scratch. I just need to get this background image working in all web based and desktop e-mail clients.

I've already had a scan through http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/, I'm guessing my best bet would be to completely slice every image and position them in tables?

If someone could give me a very basic guidance on how to do background images which work globally across all mail clients, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't expect web-based email clients to work with "complex" CSS. It's far far too easy for a stupidly designed site/email to break the containing page of the webmail client, so pretty much all of them filter out css, or at least only allow small 'safe' portions to actually get through to the browser.

Comment: Instead of this `<img>` tag hack, have you tried `background-image`?

Comment: background-image isn't supported in most e-mail clients. I'm thinking I'm going to have to go all out with tables, slice all of the image up and place it accordingly in tables. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a background image for the table, use `style="background: url(...)"` in the `<table>` tag.

E-mail programs may still refuse to download and show the background image by default, but this would appear to be the best shot.

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, Outlooks html interpreter is MS Word...

Any HTML that works when opened using MS Word will look fine in Outlook. This means, any 1990 style HTML, diagrammed by tables and stuff...

:-)

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that in my question, I'm guessing the best way would be to slice the background image in photoshop and then output it as tables and go from there.